# Post JSON data from AngularJS Client to Express Server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, post, express

I try to post a JSON Object with AngularJS $http service to an Express Server. But I get an empty object in the server : "{}"

I see this topic but this not solve my issue : [angular post json to express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675889/angular-post-json-to-express)

Here code of Angular client  :

```
self.postTicket = function(ticket){
        $http({
            url: baseUrl+"features/",
            method: "POST",
            body: ticket,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
}
```

I check the "ticket" object and it isn't empty

And here, the express server :

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({}));

app.post('*', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send('OK');
});


app.listen(9000);
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data` property instead of `body` in your `$http` call

```
$http({
            url: baseUrl+"features/",
            method: "POST",
            data: ticket,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
self.postTicket = function(ticket){
    $http({
        url: baseUrl+"features/",
        method: "POST",
        body: ticket,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

with

```
self.postTicket = function(ticket){
    $http({
        url: baseUrl+"features/",
        method: "POST",
        data: ticket,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```